# Returning object with dynamic property when typed as Record

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get the following reduced case to compile:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=6&pln=3&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFjMBzAPABUQUwA8p8wATAZ0QqgCd0MAaRANQD4AKABwC5EdmANz4sAlHwBK+CHFplczdogDeAKACQtfFBC0kyxAG0uAXT6DEAXwDcqy0A

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
function thing<P extends string, V>(p: P, v: V): { [x: string]: V; } {
    return { [p]: v }; 
}
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with it, but you're not returning a Record< P , V >

You may want to have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt